# Split 2 x N matrix into two submatrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, split, operation

I have a matrix 2 x N (lets call it MyMatrix) containing pairs of elements (element in (1,1) corresponds to element (2,1), element in (1,2) correspords to element (2,2) and so on.) Entries in first row are sorted in ascending order. What I would like to do is split this matrix into 2 matrices 2 x K and 2 x N-K. First matrix will contain part of MyMatrix where entries in row 1 are less than some given value (in my example it will be (max-min)/2 , where max = maximum value in row 1, min = minimum walue in row 1) and second matrix will consist of the rest of MyMatrix. I'm sorry if it is confusing but I tried my best to explain to you what I would like to achieve.

Here is an example:

MyMat =

```
    |1   2     4    6   13   52   65   120    125|
    |4   132   53   1   64   34   5    2      66 |
```

min = 1 , max = 125, avg = (125-1)/2 = 62.

so result will be as follows:

a =

```
|1   2     4    6   13   52 |
|4   132   53   1   64   34 |
```

b=

```
|65   120   125|
|5    2     66 |
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards,

Tom.

Comment: Please provide your example data in a valid syntax, which can be copied to matlab.

Comment: My sincere advice to you, before posting such questions. Write down this problem on a piece of paper. Imagine what your brain does to solve that problem step by step. Implement those steps in your code (optimizing code is the later part though). Most importantly, try for several hours before posting here. That's how you will learn coding skills. Please ask if you don't understand my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
a=MyMat(:,MyMat(1,:)<avg);
b=MyMat(:,MyMat(1,:)>=avg);
```